# How to deal with complex database using an ORM on Android?

Tags: sqlite

I can't find how to deal properly with complex databases using ORM on Android. I tried to find an Open Source project to see how it works but can find one that suits what i'm looking for...

I learned about relational databases some years ago and worked on SQL Server and Oracle databases, huge ones. The first things i learned when designing a database is to avoid having several times the same data. The second things i learned is never do in code what you can do with SQL. So I'm facing several problems with Android and ORM since it looks like you abolutely have to use an ORM in Android to be a good developer...

Let's take an example and say we have 100 buildings with 50 people in each of these building, all buildings has a different address. I want to get all people with their building address. I can't put this in one table else the same strings will exists many  times in the database. Since on each adress there are 50 people if I use only one table I will have the same address string 50 times for each building, so I create another table with only buildings  and make a relationship between these two tables. This is a trivial case but i saw many times Android app storing the same data many times in one or two tables.... what the point to use relational database if you replicate data ?

Again this is a simplistic example but when you have 20 or 30 tables with complex relationships the query in ORM styles can quickly become unreadable compare to SQL. Therefore not all SQL join types are generally supported by ORM. Then you use SQL raw query but what's the point to use an ORM since you can't use the object mapping since you're not returning a table you can map to a class but the result of a query... or maybe there is something I didn't understand. What the point to use an ORM if you don't use the relationnal object mapping advantage or make the queries difficultly maintainable ?

I saw a lot of code too where the ORM is used to get data in several tables and then the filtering and joining part is made using code... what's the point to use a relational database if you have to do this in code ? actually doing this some years ago what seen as the worse thing to do... but now I saw it so many times on Android...

So another solution is to create a View in the db and map my object to this view. I can use the power of SQL and the power of relationnal object mapping of the ORM. But several ORM doesn't support Views, like GreenDao who is one of the most used ORM today as far as I know...

All the example i can find here and there are not dealing with complex databases or has this kind of bad practices. Or at least it was condidered as bad practices for years... does it changed ?

So what's the best way to deal with "complex" databases on Android ?

Comment: See [Object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) and [The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/). The best way is to avoid complex databases.

Comment: Thank you the links, specially the second one it's very interesting. What is really strange to me anyway is that in Android/Java it looks like people ask themselves a  lot of questions about this and struggle to find an really acceptable solution. I was working in Microsoft world before and they don't have any problems with this. Everybody uses Entity Framework for objet relational mapping and Linq (very powerful) to deal with complex queries. It looks like it suits the needs perfectly at least everybody is happy with that. At least it was the case 2 years ago I don't know about now.

Comment: The whole point of an ORM is to avoid queries and to have *objects* appear automatically. LINQ alone is just another way to write queries, so it is not an ORM.If you use EF like an ORM, you get the same problems (see, for example, [Performance Considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949853.aspx)).

Comment: Yes, LINQ is the same as queries it's just more powerful and readable than Android ORM solutions I tried until now.  As you said you can avoid to create complex database but then if it's a relational db you'll have duplicate data, no choice. Regarding your comments and the links you provided me I think I made my choice. I'm now going deeper in nosql with Realm. The bad thing is that i love the power of SQL and now i can't use it anymore. But at least it looks like a better solution to me than create a simple SQL db and replicate data many times and loose all the advantage of SQL... thanks.

Comment: @Laurent, are you open to considering a non-open source ORM that can handle complex object models you described?

Comment: No, I'm not interested with non open source solutions. The best thing I found is to convert my SQL model to a Realm db for now.